# how to change null to empty value in http get request angular 8

Tags: angular

I am using angular to fetch data from API which has some values as null, I want to change this values to an empty string.

sample JSON from API

```
[
    {
        "id": 84,
        "employee_name": "Alan",
        "phone_number": "",
        "process": null,
        "joining_date": null
    },
    {
        "id": 85,
        "employee_name": "Bob",
        "phone_number": "",
        "process": {
            "id": 1,
            "process_name": "Moulding"
        },
        "joining_date": null
    },
]
```

I have successfully changed these null values to an empty string while displaying them in a material table. But that means repeating the same code many times, so I want to do this transformation at a higher level i.e. on an HTTP get request.

api get request

```
public getAll(): Observable<any[]> {
   return this.http.get<any[]>(`${this.apiURL}/${this.specificURL}/`);
  }
```

I think it can be done using rxjs 'map' operator but I really don't know how to do it.

Comment: combine it with `pipe(map(res =>.....))`;

Comment: Which all fields can come as null? Just **process** and **joining_date**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using map and Object.keys() to process all properties. You should modify your service like:

```
return this.http.get<any[]>(`${this.apiURL}/${this.specificURL}/`).pipe(map(res => mapNullProperties(res));
```

```js
function mapNullProperties(data) {

  return data.map(objWithNull => {
    const objWithoutNull = {...objWithNull};
    Object.keys(objWithoutNull).forEach(key => {
      if (objWithoutNull[key] === null) {
        objWithoutNull[key] = '';
      }
    });
    return objWithoutNull;
  });
}

console.log(getAll([
    {
        "id": 84,
        "employee_name": "Alan",
        "phone_number": "",
        "process": null,
        "joining_date": null
    },
    {
        "id": 85,
        "employee_name": "Bob",
        "phone_number": "",
        "process": {
            "id": 1,
            "process_name": "Moulding"
        },
        "joining_date": null
    },
]));
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't process the data and replace the value from null to ''.

What I would do is use `||` operator like this: `{{joining_date || ''}}` in the template where you show your value, so if it is null, the empty string will be used.